# Microsoft Graph - Find the original message in email chain

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am not sure if this is possible but is there a way to find the very first email message in an email chain?

For example, if there are 3 messages in email chain (1 original and 2 reply messages), I would like to find the very first original email.

I thought by filtering the messges by conversationid but that did not work.

Any help much appreciated!!!

Comment: You can use the conversationid, conversationindex properties in combination of createddatetime to see if you can able to get the [first message in an email chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0) - it should work.

Comment: For your scenario, i would test it with conversationindex only. This property indicates the position of the message within a particular conversation. It is a client's reponsibility to set PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX (MAPI field) for each outgoing message, whether it is a new message, a forwarded message, or a reply. Clients can set this property manually or call ScCreateConversationIndex, a utility function provided by MAPI.

Comment: Let me know if the above helped you.